# Can't change the background color on carousel caption with BootStrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck trying to change the background color of a simple carousel-caption.

When I check in the debugger I see the warning "Invalid property value" but I can't figure out why.

I'm wondering whether I missed something. I don't get why the property background with an rgba color would be invalid in a carousel-caption.

I've tried placing this property in the carousel-item but I got the same result.

Here's a link to the code on JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qragpevL/

```css
.html{
    font-family: Poppins;
}
.carousel-item{
    height: 80vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat center scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-caption{
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    background: rgba(black, black, black, 0.8);
}

.carousel-caption h5{
    font-size: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color:black;
}

.carousel-caption p{
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.9;
    color:black;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand{
    color:black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active
{
    color: black;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color: black;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My SportTeam</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517048676732-d65bc937f952?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Slider One Item</h5>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, aut?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Slider Two Item</h5>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, aut?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541746972996-4e0b0f43e02a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Slider Three Item</h5>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, aut?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are providing invalid values for the rgba colour scheme. Having `rgba(black,black, black, 0.8);` won't really work. Try setting it as: `rgba(0, 0, 0);` if you want it black.

Here's a link to a [css color picker tool, provided by Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool)

Comment: @Korpin create a JS fiddle example where I can poke around with the code and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've provided a jsfiddle in my initial post.

Comment: @Korpin changed my answer. See if this helps.